# check if (n)th elements contain class name

Tags: javascript

How to check if the first 3 **li** elements contain the class **yes**? Then, execute a function. Vanilla Js only, no jquery.

```
<ul>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="no">blah blah</li>
  <li class="no">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
</ul>
```

Example logic:

```
if (li[0] && li[1] && li[2] has class = yes) {
    alert("You win!");
}
else{
    alert("You lose!");
}
```

Comment: Do yo have any other means to select the li's other than class? I mean are these the only li elements on the page or do you potentially need to segregate this specific set of li's from others on the page?

Comment: Try with `querySelectorAll`, then loop or reference by index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to several great javascript solutions I will propose two more CSS-oriented options.

**1). nth-child**. You can try this approach with [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select first three children:

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('ul li.yes:nth-child(-n+3)');
if (li.length === 3) {
    // all three first elements has class "yes"
}
```

The idea is that `li.yes` will select elements with class "yes", and `:nth-child(-n+3)` makes sure that returned elements are the first three only. The result is a multiplication of those two conditions. Then we just need to check that returned result has length 3.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b1oy0d6w/

**2). sibling selectors**. Or one more a little crazy version, but even shorter using sibling selector [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
if (document.querySelector('ul li.yes:first-child + .yes + .yes')) {
    // all three first elements has class "yes"
}
```

The idea behind this approach:

1. li.yes:first-child - check that the first `li` has class "yes"
2. the next element has class "yes"
3. and the next after the second (i.e. the third) element also has class "yes".

Entire selector `ul li.yes:first-child + .yes + .yes` then returns the third `li` element, only if above three conditions are met.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b1oy0d6w/1/

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

```
// storing an Array of the first three <li> elements returned by
// document.querySelectorAll():
var firstThree = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), 0, 3);

// logging whether or not every (using Array.prototype.every())
// Array element's classList contains the class of 'yes':
console.log(firstThree.every(function(el) {
  return el.classList.contains('yes');
}));
```

```js
var firstThree = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), 0, 3);

console.log(firstThree.every(function(el) {
  return el.classList.contains('yes');
}));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="no">blah blah</li>
  <li class="no">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
  <li class="yes">blah blah</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Comment: I would also mention that classList is cool, but it's IE10+ only.

Comment: `classList` *is* cool :) And there's a shim in the referenced page (which, admittedly, I'd forgotten to add to the answer until I read your comment).

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id="ul"` to the UL element then run:

```
var el=document.getElementById('ul');
var li=el.getElementsByTagName('li');
if(
/ yes /.test(' '+li[0].className+' ')&&
/ yes /.test(' '+li[1].className+' ')&&
/ yes /.test(' '+li[2].className+' ')
){
alert('you win');
}else{
    alert("You lose!");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9sev1hq/

Comment: It's good practice to make sure you select the `UL` we're working on and not some other UL on the page before we get to work. We're only being given a portion of the HTML, and we need to first uniquely select the container element from the HTML page. Adding an ID to the element is only good practice. If the HTML is so tight that we can't add an id to it, simply use `var el=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt be too tough, try:

```
var answer = true
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li") // Gets all the <lis> in all the uls
var classes = lis.map(function (e) {return e.className} //list of classnames
for (e in classes.splice(0,3)) { // runs a function on each of the first 3 elements
    answer = (e == "yes") && answer // if any of the elements isnt "yes", answer will become false
}
if (answer) {
    alert("You win!!!!!!!")
} else {
    alert("You lose")
}
```